# eval() Not Iterating but String Does

Tags: php, arrays, string, while-loop, eval

I am using a while loop to loop through an array and set a dynamic variable with the output of an array. This works fine, however I would then like to echo the values in a string that is generated on each loop. The string is pulled from a server. I know I need to evaluate that string so I am using eval() however, instead of having a new value on each loop the eval seems to hold onto the first value.

When I supply the output string inline as a echo it produces multiple lines with the dynamic data from the array.

Below is the code I have. $value is the string that is pulled from a server side database. It is "**Description of Gift:** $giftDesc **Given to:** $giftGiven" without the quotes.

```
while ($i < 3){
    $keys = $keywords[$i];
    $array = $_POST[$keys];
    $$keywords[$i] = $array[$ii];
    $i++;
}
eval("\$value = \"$value\";"); 
echo $value;
```

This returns:

```
Description of Gift: Gift1 
Given to: Given 1

Description of Gift: Gift1
Given to: Given 1
```

However if I do the below code:

```
while ($i < 3){
    $keys = $keywords[$i];
    $array = $_POST[$keys];
    $$keywords[$i] = $array[$ii];
    $i++;
}
print "<strong>Description of Gift: </strong>$giftDesc<strong>Given to: </strong>$giftGiven";
```

This returns:

```
Description of Gift: Gift1 
Given to: Given 1

Description of Gift: Gift2
Given to: Given 2
```

So, the question is why does eval() not change upon each loop?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: var-vars and eval(): two major signs that you REALLY need to rethink your code.

Comment: Have a look at the `printf` function. You can do something like: `printf("Description of gift: %s Given to: %s", $giftDesc, $giftGiven);`. No need for all this nasty `eval` business.

Comment: Your code example does not have enough information in it to answer your question properly. Where is `$value` coming from? What is in `$keywords` and `$_POST`?

Answer (score 0):

Your `eval` is outside of the loop. It is only run once.

Comment: Oh yes. Well, actually this loop is in another loop so in this case it loops twice. That part works fine I do get 2 lines of the eval they are just the same each time.